# Scaling Error/Axis Error in D3.js

Tags: svg, d3.js

I am new to D3 and have been working along with examples and changing correcting my code using those examples,

Below is my D3 Code and it works well except the bar chart is not scaled, I seem to not understand the error on my part.

The data is coming from a TSV file and has 2 columns, 1- Categorical 2- Numerical.

[image]

```
<script type = "text/javascript">

var margin = { top:80, bottom:80, right:80, left:80},
    width = 960 - margin.left-margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width",width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height",height + margin.top + margin. bottom)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate("+margin.left+"," + margin.bottom+")");

d3.tsv("ticket.tsv",function(error, data) { 
dataset = data.map(function(d) { return [d["ticket"],+d["num"] ] ;})

var xScale  = d3.scale.ordinal()
.domain(data.map(function(d){ return [d.ticket];}))
.rangeRoundBands([0,width],0.1);

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
.domain([0,d3.max(data,function(d) { return Math.max([d.num]);})])
.range([height, 0]);


var rect = svg.selectAll("rect")
.data(data)
.enter()
.append("rect")
.attr("x",function(d,i) { return xScale(d.ticket);})
.attr("y",function (d) { return height - (yScale (d.num)) ;})
.attr("height",function (d) { return d.num;})
.attr("width",xScale.rangeBand())
.attr("fill","orange");

var xAxis  = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(xScale)
            .orient("bottom");

var yAxis  = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(yScale)
            .orient("left");

svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "axis")
.attr("transform", "translate(0"+","+(height)+")")
.call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "axis")
.call(yAxis);
;});
</script>
```

Comment: You probably want `yScale(d.num)` for the height instead of just `d.num`.

Comment: Thanks that worked but now none of the heights are scaled to the yaxis. They are approximately half now.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Could you update the picture please?

Comment: got it , In the code I was subtracting height from yscale(d.num) for "y" although i should have done subtracted it with "height" and off course your suggestion also helped. Thanks a ton!

Comment: I have updated the code and picture as you suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Solved Code and Picture, **I have commented the code I have corrected.**

[image]

```
<script type = "text/javascript">

var margin = { top:80, bottom:80, right:80, left:80},
    width = 960 - margin.left-margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width",width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height",height + margin.top + margin. bottom)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate("+margin.left+"," + margin.bottom+")");

d3.tsv("tickets.tsv",function(error, data) { 
dataset = data.map(function(d) { return [d["ticket"],+d["num"] ] ;})

var xScale  = d3.scale.ordinal()
.domain(data.map(function(d){ return [d.ticket];}))
.rangeRoundBands([0,width],0.1);

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
.domain([0,d3.max(data,function(d) { return Math.max([d.num]);})])
.range([height,0]);


var rect = svg.selectAll("rect")
.data(data)
.enter()
.append("rect")
.attr("x",function(d) { return xScale(d.ticket);})
.attr("y",function (d) { return yScale (d.num) ;})**//I made the change HERE** 
.attr("height",function (d) { return height - yScale(d.num);})**// and HERE**
.attr("width",xScale.rangeBand())
.attr("fill","orange");

var xAxis  = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(xScale)
            .orient("bottom");

var yAxis  = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(yScale)
            .orient("left");

svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "axis")
.attr("transform", "translate(0"+","+(height)+")")
.call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "axis")
.call(yAxis);


;});

</script>
```